# Get from a Draggrable Marker new street and town

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've a google maps with a draggrabble marker that in infowindow show the street and town

NOw I use this code to get new lng e lat in a form when marker is dragged

---

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  if (results[1]) {
    infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  } else {
    window.alert('No results found');
  }
 } else {
  window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
 }
 });
 }

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
document.getElementById("lat").value = this.getPosition().lat();
document.getElementById("lng").value = this.getPosition().lng(); 
document.getElementById("latlng").value =  this.getPosition().lat()+','+this.getPosition().lng();
geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
});
```

In the input lng, lat, latlng all is ok so the value change moving the marker, but I can determine the value of 2 other input that are city and street

I'm looking for something like

```
document.getElementById("address").value = this.address;
document.getElementById("city").value = this.city;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result components contain element [organized in this way](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering)

```
results[0].components
```

filtering n.th  result[0].components[n].types by the

- **route** matches long or short name of a route.
- **locality** matches against both locality and sublocality types.
- **administrative_area** matches all the administrative_area levels (administrative_area_level_3.political = town/city , administrative_area_level_2.political  = province/county, administrative_area_level_1.political  = country)
- **postal_code** matches postal_code and postal_code_prefix.
- **country matches** a country name or a two letter ISO 3166-1 country code.

you can get what you need in

```
   result[0].components[n].long_name
```

if you want only locality you should iterate this way

```
  for  (var i=0;  i < results[0].address_components.length; i++ ) {
      if (results[0].address_components[i].types  == 'locality,political') {
        window.alert(results[0].address_components[i].long_name);
      };
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried document.getElementById("address").value = result[0].components["locality"].long_name

But it doesn't work

Comment: Hi, scaisEdge, I've put your code "for...." before "document.getElementById("lat").value = this.getPosition().lat();
" but it gives this problem Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier